# How to slow down flare animation from seconds to hours

Tags: android, ios, animation, flutter, web-applications

I am developing an animation for solar tracking app. In that the sun has to revolve around the given arc for 12 hours or even more.

I have created the animation in Flare (now Rive) with a duration of 30 secs, but I need to extend the duration up to 12 hours. Is there a way to expand the duration of the animation in Flutter?

Link to the animation:
https://rive.app/a/PraveenKumar/files/flare/solar-tracking/preview

Comment: You can try this solution https://github.com/2d-inc/Flare-Flutter/issues/167#issuecomment-558875870

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a way to put 720 minutes ?

Like 720:00:00 (There is and I've tried =D)

BUT...

Will it have any issues ? Maybe the animation become to large for it. Another solution is to manually change the position dinamically using time.

Comment: can you give me the code to slow down the animation using time

and also to reset the animation at particular time